# Does potential decrease across capacitors on moving from +ve terminal of cell to -ve terminal?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

If I have two capacitors connected in series across a cell, does potential always decrease successively across the capacitors as I move from the +ve terminal of the cell to the -ve terminal, or is it possible that potential first increases across one of the capacitors and then decreases across the other capacitor?
[image]

For example, in the above diagram, as I move from the +ve terminal of the cell to the negative terminal along the circuit, what guarantee is there that potential will decrease across the 2 micro Farad capacitor connected directly to the +ve terminal.
It can also be that potential first increases across the 2 micro Farad capacitor connected directly to the +ve terminal and then decreases across the 4 micro Farad capacitor connected to the lower branch (below path ab). Yet, the solution in the book pre assumes that potential must decrease across the 2 micro Farad capacitor connected directly to the +ve terminal.

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Answer (score 2):

As there is no DC path between terminal a and any other terminal, it could indeed have any potential with respect to the others (and in real life you could expect it to), and so possibly increase as you surmise.

However, there is a (usually unstated) assumption when answering problems like these, that all the capacitors start off uncharged, and then the battery gets connected. This is what the book solution assumes.

With the problem as illustrated on the left, there is no solution to the voltages on the capacitor nodes. Nodes a, c can have any arbitrary voltage with respect to b.

I've added a ground terminal, which does not change the operation of the circuit, just shows which node I am defining to be at zero voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1mGLx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What you are intended to solve is the problem on the right. Starting with the switch open, and all the capacitors at zero volts, so nodes a and c at zero volts, close the switch, and solve for the new voltages.

The way I would solve this is to first combine the capacitors into a single capacitor after the switch, to work out how much charge flows through the switch when it closes. This charge charges C8, so you can work out the voltage on c. You now need to split this charge flow between the parallel connection of C5, and C6+C7, in the ratio of their capacitances, which will charge these capacitors.

The above is for working out the actual voltages quantitatively. Qualitatively, you will see just by inspection that all the nodes will be at a higher voltage than ground, and those closer to the battery +ve will be at a higher voltage than the others, just because charge flows from the battery, into the capacitors. And so in this case, potential happens to decrease as you move from the +ve terminal of the cell to the -ve terminal.

Comment: Ok, so is it right if I say that the fact that potential decreases across the 2 micro Farad capacitor connected directly to the +ve terminal, is just an assumption for solving the problem?

Comment: Also, I did not understand what the second paragraph of your answer is trying to imply

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee   `Ok, so is it right if I say that the fact that potential decreases across the 2 micro Farad capacitor connected directly to the +ve terminal` that's not an assumption, that's a consequence of solving the circuit under the first assumption. If you don't understand my second paragraph, then you don't understand how to solve the problem a t all

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee One aspect of your question is the voltage source, itself. Let's say, for example, that I have a voltage source with a potential difference of 10 kV. (HV.) But no galvanic connection. Just open vacuum. How much charge is sitting at one end vs the other end? Now, suppose I provide a conductive path that provides 1 mA of current over a distance of 1 meter. (10 MegOhm spanning a meter length.) How much charge is present at the (+) terminal? How much at the (-) terminal? What's the surface charge gradient over the length? (At the center, the surface charge should be neutral.)

Comment: @Neil_UK , I am saying I don't understand how the second paragraph answers the question, that is what I am saying. If you can please expand it some more, it will be helpful